# Why my car RPM goes up while Parked

Tags: engine, rpm

Please help. I drive a Toyota Spacio 2002 but after driving for a while when I change from drive to P (Park) the RPM needle moves up slightly and there is some noticeable change in the sound of my vehicle. Please where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This does not mean there is a problem.

When you take it out of gear (R or D) and put it into park you change the demand on the engine from the gearbox and the fluid flywheel, this allows the engine to idle slightly higher.

When you put it in gear again you will probably notice a slight drop, if the change either way (into or out of gear) is only 50rpm or so then it should not be a problem.

**If** , however, the engine goes from 900rpm to 600rpm when you move from park to drive then that does need to be looked at.